# NotifyIcon With Buttons

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I'm looking for a way to leave buttons in the windows tray. I've already tried searching for NotifyIcon with buttons, but there's no way, at least not with NotifyIcons. Here's an example of buttons:

[image: Tray]

Comment: There are no buttons in that screenshot.  NotifyIcon has excellent support for a context menu.

Comment: @HansPassant the buttons I'm talking about are these "Painel de controle da NVIDIA" and "NVIDIA GeForce Experience" and "Sair". My problem is that I'm not able to create them using NotifyIcon

Comment: They are context menu items.  Drop a ContextMenuStrip on the form to get started.

Comment: @HansPassant I did some research, and I managed to do it, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a context menu or something like that.
Then just do.

```
 notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = contextMenu1;
```

then just create contextmenu then add your buttons and ui.